# Clear some stuff from Nailgun cache (usage: Jython)

Tags: java, caching, jython, nailgun

This is a bit technical, and follows on from [Using Nailgun in Eclipse for Java and Jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765658/using-nailgun-in-eclipse-for-java-and-jython).

I have found out how to get Nailgun to work OK in on a Windows OS in Eclipse, using Jython.  And using the unittest module.

What is baffling is that sometimes I make a change to a .py file, and sometimes (not always), an older version of this file continues to be run.  This can even persist when I close down the Nailgun server, close its window, and start it up again: an old version of a file is being run, which no longer exists.

This feels very much like a cache problem.  My understanding is that Jython does not generate .class files usually (although sometimes it does if you import a module??).

But perhaps this is indeed what Nailgun is doing.  I have done some searching on my C: drive to see whether this cache location might be easy to locate: no luck.

Essentially I need the ability to tell Nailgun, between app runs, to delete a given .class file from whatever cache arrangement it maintains.

Incidentally, it doesn't matter whether the CLASSPATH elements in question are stipulated in the server's "SET CLASSPATH=..." or using the "ng-cp" option in the ng command line (i.e. in the client).

If all else fails I shall probably have to look into the NG source for inspiration.  Gulp.